# Use fseek to print any arbitrary record

Tags: c, file, fseek

How do I use fseek to find any arbitrary record and print that record? specifically the third record.
The file format:

```
first name
last name
gpa
```

my code (assume the file already exists):

```
typedef struct
{
    char first [20], last[20];
    double gpa;
} Student;

int main ()
{
    Student student;
    FILE* file = fopen ("gpa.dat", "r+");

    fseek(file, sizeof(Student), SEEK_END);
    fread(&student, sizeof(student), 1, file);

    printf("Name: %s %s\nGPA: %lf\n", student.first, student.last, student.gpa);

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

So if the third record is

```
xxx
yyy
3.56
```

thats what I want printed

Comment: Why must you use `fseek` for this task?

Comment: Is it a text file or a binary file with fixed-size records?

Comment: How was `gpa.dat` created?

Comment: [fseek](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fseek) moves the file pointer in bytes , that can be from start of the file `SEEK_SET` or any current position  `SEEK_CUR` or from end to backward `SEEK_END`

Comment: `gpa.dat` was created by getting input from stdin then using fwrite if thats what you mean? @Johnny Mopp. Its a text file with a growable sized records @Barmar.

Comment: That's what you need to show and then we will be able to tell you the ***offset*** required to reach an individual record.

Comment: how I created the file was irrelevant @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: Well, no, not it's not, but presuming you wrote some number of `struct Student` with `fwrite`, then your offset is `sizeof (struct Student) * no_of_records_to_skip`, but **be aware** the file you write is not guaranteed to be readable by another compiler due to differences in padding between the members for which no standard exists. That is why you want to *Serialize* your data written to file. That said, for an exercise on a single computer using the same compiler -- you will be fine.

Comment: `sizeof (struct Student) * no_of_records_to_skip` was what I was looking for @DavidC.Rankin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `b` modifier in the open mode if you're reading a binary file.

To get to an arbitrary record, multiply `sizeof(Student)` by the zero-baed record number. And use `SEEK_SET` to count from the beginning of the file.

```
int main ()
{
    Student student;
    FILE* file = fopen ("gpa.dat", "rb+");
    int record_num = 3;

    fseek(file, record_num * sizeof(Student), SEEK_SET);
    fread(&student, sizeof(student), 1, file);

    printf("Name: %s %s\nGPA: %lf\n", student.first, student.last, student.gpa);

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```